# R Studio package install issue

Tags: r, r-package

When I am downloading package `dLagM` in RStudio, it gives an error again and again to re-download it, and when I load it from `library()` it gives an error that `dLagM` is not installed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you include the code and both error messages into your question, please and also the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: I am following these step wise procedure 

Step#1 install.packages("dLagM")

then i RUN it and gives these replies 

1.Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Kashii/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘rio’, ‘car’, ‘dynlm’, ‘AER’

2. There are binary versions available but the
  source versions are later:
      binary source needs_compilation
rio   0.5.10 0.5.16             FALSE
car    3.0-0  3.0-2             FALSE
dynlm  0.3-5  0.3-6             FALSE
AER    1.2-5  1.2-6             FALSE
dLagM  1.0.2 1.0.10             FALSE’

Comment: and in the last it gives 
installing the source packages ‘rio’, ‘car’, ‘dynlm’, ‘AER’, ‘dLagM

even i download these all packages  ‘rio’, ‘car’, ‘dynlm’, ‘AER’,and in the last  ‘dLagM but all work is useless , it gives error again

Comment: Two points for consideration: 1) Please ***edit your question*** with the additional information, rather than paste un-formatted error messages into the comment box. 2) Your R version appears to be 3.3, which is outdated by 2 years at this point. You may wish to update that first.